# Windows 7 touch and hold move/jitter tolerance

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, touchscreen

I recently acquired a tablet PC with a Wacom resistive touchscreen, and doing a right click on it is almost impossible, most of the time the computer interprets it as a drag event because of noise or small, unintentional movements of the stylus/finger.

Is there a way to tell Windows to ignore drags up to a certain distance around the current touch point, so that it doesn't happen anymore ?

Comment: Are you using a CRT screen? They really mess up Wacoms. [idk the answer to your actual Q, sorry]

Comment: @Tetsujin of course not, I'm using the default LCD screen from the laptop itself. As for the Wacom, it's actually *not* a tablet but a touchscreen overlay placed on the laptop's LCD itself (I guess they manufacture those for OEMs).

Comment: hmmm… not seen one of those - they used to do 'actual' touchscreens, with pen. mouse etc - so you could see as you draw, long before they were a real commercial finger-touch viability, though I could never afford one ;) Equivalent to US $600 15 years ago for an A4 tablet was my first & last outlay on one.

Comment: ouch... but I bet they're lovely to use…next time I win the lottery ;) I did like the 'allow an extra 10 days because of high demand' on a 2 grand+ display… but I digress - sorry, I have no clue, my jitter vanished with my last CRT, since then it's been sweet.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm pretty sure the jitter won't be there with the pen... except I don't have the original pen and I'm just using whatever object I have (my finger nail or a conventional pen) and the tablet only recognizes it as a touch event which apparently doesn't have any smoothing and has this nasty 1px jitter (unless I hold the object really straight and press hard on it, which gets pretty annoying)..

Comment: The pen is not a 'touch device' it's an induction device, you cannot replace it with a pencil/knitting needle/finger etc. It simply will not work the same way.

Comment: I've never used a Wacom that would even respond in any way whatsoever to anything other than a Wacom interactive 'tool', so I'm afraid I can't help, sorry.

Comment: @Tetsujin I guess these touchscreens that Wacom makes for OEMs are a bit special, but I can assure you this one definitely reacts to my touch as I'm using it right now instead of the mouse. And no problem, thanks anyway :)